# What are snap mounts on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: mount, 18.04, snap

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 from live USB. It went well, however I see some snap folders mounted.

```
/dev/loop1       21M   21M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/25
/dev/loop4      1,7M  1,7M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/154
/dev/loop2      3,4M  3,4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
/dev/loop3       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/69
/dev/loop0       87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4486
/dev/loop5      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
```

Are these mounts important? How can I get rid of it if not?